# Correspondence between tensors and multivectors

Tags: tensor-products, clifford-algebras

In one of its definitions the Clifford algebra is defined as a quotient space of a (infinite dimensional) Tensor algebra.
The question is: 
Given the metric signature and the tensor $T$ and its transformation law how is it possible to represent it in the multivector basis of the Clifford algebra with the same signature?